# I don't know why this three.js example doesn't work

Tags: javascript, three.js

I installed three.js through npm with the command: npm install --save three
I'm currently using VS-Code & have two files : index.html and index.js
By copying a simple example from threejs.org I can't seem to get three.js to work,because i only get a blank screen after running a live server,instead of a rotating cube.

Here's  the code to both files:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 
0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate)

cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

renderer.render( scene, camera )
}
animate();
```

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "index.css">
<script src = "index.js"></script>
<title >Title</title>
</head>

<body style = "margin: 0px;">


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open the page in a browser and take a look at the dev tools menu, you'll find the following error:[image].

If you modify the script tag with `type="module"` to resolve this error, you get a new error: `Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`.

Basically, the browser isn't able to find the three.js JavaScript library.

One easy fix is to just tell the browser to load the library from a web url when the page loads instead of installing it through npm and then loading those installed npm files into the web page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "index.css">
<!-- This script tag loads the three.js library via url -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
<title >Title</title>
</head>

<body style = "margin: 0px;">
<script src = "index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// import is no longer needed since the added script tag loads the library and adds the global THREE variable into the page
// import * as THREE from 'three';
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 
0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)

  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render( scene, camera )
}
animate();
```

Also note that `document.body.appendChild` will only work once the document has loaded (which doesn't necessarily happen before your script is executed). This issue was fixed by adding your `<script>` tag below the `<body>` tag in the html.